# How to make angularjs unique list all results?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm using AngularJS to list and filter a task board. I'm also using `unique` to remove repeated strings in `ng-options`.
When I load the page, angular is listing well all json, but when I try to use `<select>` to filter contents, it returns me only 1 result.

For example: In json, I have 2 arrays that have `Feb`. If I choose `Feb` on `<select>`, it only returns me 1 result instead of 2. What am I doing wrong?

html:

```
<body ng-controller="ListTask">
    <div>
        <select bg-model="categoryFilter" ng-options="task.category for task in tasks | unique: 'category'">
            <option value="">category</option>
        </select>
        <select ng-model="statusFilter" ng-options="task.status for task in tasks | unique: 'status'">
            <option value="">status</option>
        </select>
        <select ng-model="monthFilter" ng-options="task.month for task in tasks | unique: 'month'">
            <option value="">month</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <li ng-repeat="tasks in task | filter: categoryFilter | filter: statusFilter | filter: monthFilter">
            <p>{{task.title}}</p>
            <small>{{task.month}} {{task.category}}</small>
        </li>
    </div>
</body>
```

json:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Title 1",
        "status": "open",
        "month": "Feb",
        "category": "Cat 1"
    },
    {
        "title": "Title 2",
        "status": "closed",
        "month": "Feb",
        "category": "Cat 2"
    },
    {
        "title": "Title 3",
        "status": "delayed",
        "month": "Mar",
        "category": "Cat 1"
    },
    {
        "title": "Title 4",
        "status": "closed",
        "month": "Mar",
        "category": "Cat 3"
    }
]
```

controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.utils']);

myApp.controller('ListTask', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('/json/tasks.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.tasks = data;
    });
}]);
```

EDIT>>>>>>>>
Another problem is when I fill more than 1 `<select>`, it returns me no results :(

Comment: how can unique list all results, you your self restricted it to remain unique, so one of the Feb will be shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that the model `monthFilter` when month is selected looks like this:

```
{"title":"Title 1","status":"open","month":"Feb","category":"Cat 1"}
```

So when you use `filter: monthFilter` it naturally matches **only one** record.

To fix it your filtering expression should look like this:

```
ng-repeat="task in tasks | filter: {category: categoryFilter.category, month: monthFilter.month, status: statusFilter.status}"
```

Above solution is pretty verbose though. Much better way to handle filtering would be to have only one filter model with properties for month, status and category:

```
<div>
    <select ng-model="filter.category" 
            ng-change="clear('category')"
            ng-options="task.category as task.category for task in tasks | unique: 'category'">
        <option value="">category</option>
    </select>
    <select ng-model="filter.status" 
            ng-change="clear('status')"
            ng-options="task.status as task.status for task in tasks | unique: 'status'">
        <option value="">status</option>
    </select>
    <select ng-model="filter.month" 
            ng-change="clear('month')"
            ng-options="task.month as task.month for task in tasks | unique: 'month'">
        <option value="">month</option>
    </select>
    {{filter}}
</div>
<div>
    <li ng-repeat="task in tasks | filter: filter">
        <p>{{task.title}}</p>
        <small>{{task.month}} {{task.category}}</small>
    </li>
</div>
```

There is only one more thing to take care of. When you select value from selectbox it filter well. However if you want to clear selection it will not filter anything, because filter model in this case will look like this when nothing is selected:

```
{month: null}
```

To handle this situation I added ngChange directive to remove `null` values:

```
$scope.clear = function(key) {
    if ($scope.filter[key] === null) {
        delete $scope.filter[key];
    }
};
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/eE9TgjSPjcSgBnCWiMTS?p=preview

Comment: Dude, I love you! It worked like a charm! Only one more question, is it possible to enable the filter inside the `<select>`? for example, if I chose `Feb` it returns me on the others select `status` and `category` or in the oposite order?

Comment: Hm, so you want select values to depend on other filters?

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant. Oh, I was searching for this clear, thanks! But where should I put this `$scope.clear`? I just tried to insert it inside `$http.get` callback, but it didnt work.

Comment: I found it! I can call it outside the callback

Comment: Yes, just declare it in the controller scope.

Comment: @RamonVasconcelos Hey, regarding you question with dependent selectboxes. Looks like I figured it out, take a look at the updated demo. The idea is to use this expression fo ngOptions: `ng-options="task.category as task.category for task in tasks | filter:filter | unique: 'category'"`. Pretty simple!